# Shopware6 - not able to get values due to my foreach loop

Tags: php, symfony, data-access-layer, shopware

We currently have this code to get some property group options :

```
//Nederlands & English
$languages = ['94a1a2d118464bdaab37d6e05d404508', '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b'];
$context = new Context(new SystemSource(), [], Defaults::CURRENCY, $languages);
$criteria = new Criteria();

Foreach ($propertiesArray as $property)
{
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $property['name']);
    $lineInfo = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
    var_dump($lineInfo);
}
```

For some reason, it's not able to get the value 'Zilver' and $lineInfo returns empty object. But the value '**Zilver**' is Existing in the db with the language_id of '**Nederlands**' = 94a1a2d118464bdaab37d6e05d404508 (Given in the context).

Strange fact : It is perfectly working for the first item of my $propertiesArray array. If I try to replace $property['value'] by 'Zilver' manually and isolate it from the foreach loop, I can get the result I need.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstood the way it works?

Here is the dump of $propertiesArray =

```
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(10) "Eenkleurig"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(6) "Zilver"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        string(5) "Praag"
      }
```

Info : the main language of our instance is English but we are currently working with a system who sends us values in Nederlands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about shopware but, your logic appears to be flawed as you are adding an additional `EqualsFilter` to the same `Criteria` in each iteration. That's why only the first search is successful.
Try creating a new `Criteria` *inside* the loop.

```
//Nederlands & English
$languages = ['94a1a2d118464bdaab37d6e05d404508', '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b'];
$context = new Context(new SystemSource(), [], Defaults::CURRENCY, $languages);

Foreach ($propertiesArray as $property)
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', $property['name']);
    $lineInfo = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, $context)->first();
    var_dump($lineInfo);
}
```

After looking through the docs, I think you may actually want to use the [`EqualsAnyFilter`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/core-reference/dal-reference/filters-reference#equalsany) and then you should only need to make one query to the database. This should be much more efficient.

```
//Nederlands & English
$languages = ['94a1a2d118464bdaab37d6e05d404508', '2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b'];
$context = new Context(new SystemSource(), [], Defaults::CURRENCY, $languages);
$criteria = new Criteria();

$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('name', array_column($propertiesArray, 'name')));
$results= $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, $context);
var_dump($results);
```